# How to upload custom app image (tab_image) for Timeline Page tabs via API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-timeline

Facebook released the new [Timeline for Pages](http://www.facebook.com/about/pages/) today. Apps installed to pages as "tabs" now appear above the timeline with a 111px x 74px size thumbnail "app image". You can customize this on a per-page level (just like the custom tab name) if you navigate the Facebook Page admin interface.

You can update the tab's "custom name" via the [Open Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs), but they do not appear to have updated their API docs to show how to upload a custom tab_image (assuming they will). Is it possible now but undocumented? Has anyone figured out how to do this yet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Updated 2016:

With the latest Open Graph 2.5 API [`tabs` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs/) and [PHP SDK 5](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4), the code should look like this:

```
<?php 
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([/* . . . */]);
$response = $fb->post(
    '/{page-id}/tabs',
    [
        'custom_name'=>'My Custom Tab',
        'custom_image_url'=>'http://publicly.accessible/image.jpg',
        'app_id'=>'{app-id}',
    ],
    '{page-access-token}',
);
```

#### Original 2012 post:

I figured it out, it's just like uploading an image. The field is called "custom_image". Presumably they will update the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs/) soon. It's nice they enabled this API hook so quickly with the new release!

Here's how to do it with the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk):

```
<?php
$page_access_token = 'XXXXXXX'; // you'll need the manage_pages permission to get this
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
  'fileUpload' => true, // enables CURL @ file uploads
));
$facebook->api(
  '/PAGE_ID/tabs/TAB_NAME', // looks like "app_xxxx" where xxxx = APP_ID
  'POST' // post to update
  array(
    'custom_image' => '@' . realpath('path/to/my/file.jpg'),
    'custom_name' => 'My App', // give it a custom name if you want too
    'access_token' => $page_access_token // access token for the page
  )
);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As you said [Timeline for Pages](http://www.facebook.com/about/pages/) is just announced and it's too soon to say it'll be possible via API. Currently it's not possible even in settings of your App in Developer Application.

This information is simply not yet documented in help center or Graph API documentation.

It's also way soon to say someone have discovered if such functionality exists...

We all should wait a bit and probably file bugs which may get some response from officials confirming, rejecting or adding this to wish list.

Comment: Even though it's not documented yet I did find a way to do this, and just posted it. Cheers